# C++ Exception Handling: Regarding 'try' block

Tags: c++, exception

In C++ what is the use of 'try' block? (when we are clearly 'throw'ing the issue)
I think in Java, exception can be find at any place in the 'try' block without having 'throw' statement.

otherwise 'try' is syntactical requirement to make 'throw' works?

correct me please if any part of my question wrong.

Comment: If you don't have a `try` you can't have a `catch`.

Comment: What are the best resources on the topic you've found so far? It'd help if those were included in the question.

Comment: There is no such syntactical requirement. You don't need `try` block to throw an exception.

Comment: try marks the block of code inside that will be executed. catch does not apply to an  arbitrary exception, anywhere, but only to the code between try's left and right brace. So it is not syntactic sugar

Answer (score 0):

The use of a try-block in C++ is the same as the use of a try-block in Java, as far as I know. The syntax for `finally` differs, but the principles are the same. Since your understanding of Java did not answer your question for you, I'll give an explanation ignoring the question's Java reference. *(This is not intended as a full explanation of exception handling, just of the use of a try-block. More information is available in various references on the subject.)*

Suppose an exception is thrown. How do you prevent that from ending your program? You have to catch it. (Makes sense so far? Throwing something with the expectation that it will be caught?) How do you catch an exception? With the "catch" keyword.

OK, let's look up the "[catch](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/catch)" keyword in a handy online reference, such as cppreference.com. This particular reference directs you to [try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch), where the use of "catch" is described. Specifically, "catch" is used as part of a try-block. (The try-block does not consist of just "try" followed by a compound statement; **the `catch` clauses are also part of the try-block**.) In order to use the "catch" keyword in your program, your program needs a try-block.

In summary, the use of a try-block is to catch exceptions. If you have no try-blocks in your program, then the first thrown exception will `terminate` your program.

Comment: I think in Java 'throw' keyword is not required, the instruction itself do everything. 

Suppose(in Java) if try block contains 10 lines, at any line exception can be thrown.(but in C++) if u have a throw statement then only exception will be handled properly. considering there exists exact catch option is available in both cases. 

Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: @Raj that is a claim about "`throw`". Whether or not it is correct is irrelevant to this question about "`try`".